# How to set both a background colour and a different text color on the same element

Tags: html, css

I have an un-ordered list with link tags inside and I would like to change the color of the background and the text when the list is hovered by the users mouse.

Here is my html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">text</a></li>
<li><a href="">text</a></li>
<li><a href="">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my css:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #60266f;
        }
```

I can't seem to work out how to apply a text color to the li tags as well as a background color.

Can anyone explain where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is setting a color to a:hover, and it would override any color style you put in `li:hover`

You can add a style to it using CSS like this:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #60266f;
}
li:hover a {  
    color: #f00;
}
```

You can see it in this JS fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/eytbzuq8/

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between `background-color:` (or `background:`) and `color`.

That last one is the one you're looking for.

**Details:**

- `li:hover {background: red;}` to set the background of
  the list-item.
- `li:hover a {color: yellow;}` to set the text-color of the a inside the list item.

**Notes:**

- Instead of `li a:hover` I used `li:hover a` because this will cause the text color to change if you only hover the list item itself. Sometimes these list items might be bigger than the link itself.
- I did not use a comma to combine `li:hover` and `li:hover a`. This makes it possible to change text outside the link to another color than the link itself.

**Example:**

```css
li:hover {color: red; background: cyan;}
li:hover a {color: yellow; background: red;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#Link1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#Link2">Link 2</a> with some text outside the a-tag.
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li a{ display:inline-block; color:red; background:black }
li a:hover{ color:white; background:green; }
```

Comment: It's better to use `li:hover a` instead of `li a:hover` since the whole li element might be bigger than the link itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

First you make the background on the li, second you make the color of text

**CSS**

```
li:hover, li:hover a {
    background: #60266f;
     color: #fff;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/57/)**